# Determining Build configuration of a Sencha Touch and ExtJS project

Tags: javascript, extjs, build, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

In sencha touch you can build a project in any of the following build configuration

1. production
2. testing
3. native
4. package

Is there any class/method/funciton in ST2 that returns the current build configuration name?

Same goes for ExtJs (not to be confused with sencha touch).

I want to dump (`console.log`) a lot of debugging information on on `testing` or `debug` configuration.